# 'Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'user' between objects in different contexts

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

can someone please help me make sense of this error, it happens at the randomest times and I have no idea how to debug, since there is nothing I can find online.

-It's saying that I am trying to establish a relation between objects in different contexts but I only have one context

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'user' between objects in different contexts (source =  (entity: Mesages; id: 0x6000000391e0  ; data: {
>       fromID = nil;
>       isSender = nil;
>       seen = nil;
>       status = nil;
>       text = G;
>       timestamp = "2016-10-13 01:24:16 +0000";
>       toID = nil;
>       user = nil;
>   }) , destination =  (entity: Friend; id: 0xd000000000180000  ; data: ))'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>
> ...
>
> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (Recorded Frame)

Comment: show the code please

Comment: did set your parent context ?

Comment: no I didnt why would I need that I only have one context??

Comment: your error saying there have two context however if have one then  try to Property Injection perfectly .

Comment: Possibly one of the two contexts is a nil context - i.e. You have one object that is not associated with any context and the other object is registered with your context.

Comment: That makes sense.. i have a relationship between messages and friend

Comment: How do you set a context to nil..

Comment: @slimboy When you create NSManagedObjects using the designated initialiser you have to specify the context.  It is possible to specify a nil context at this point (the context argument in `init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertInto context: NSManagedObjectContext?)` is optional), so double check that your context is not nil when you create the Message and Friend objects.